# How to generate select or insert script of table using SSDT in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Is it possible to generate select or insert script of one table using SSDT in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish, like why you are using SSDT to generate scripts?

Comment: I am using local database with visual studio that is why I am trying to generate script with VS2013

Comment: What are you trying to generate, though? Are you trying to use a GUI query builder like the graphical view designer in SSMS? Are you trying to use a GUI to write your code? You'd normally type those out or if you're trying to save them for the future, you'd want to save them as stored procedures, functions, or views in your project. You can open a SQL query window, but there's no easy "select/insert" functionality like SSMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across this entry hoping it would answer this question: how do I script out the data in a table?  I've used SSMS in the past to generate the INSERT statements that would load the data back into a table.

These are the steps in VS 2013/SSDT 2014:

1. Using the SQL Server Object Explorer pane, right click on the table name, choose `View Data`.
2. At the top of the data pane is label `Max Rows` with combo box, choose `All`.
3. Click on scroll/script icon to right of box and it will produce script of insert statements.
4. The next icon to the right will send the statements straight to file.

Comment: How this can be done automatically for multiple tables?